# Extract the metadata from a jpeg or png file in exif format

Tags: java, eclipse, metadata-extractor

I want to be able to extract the metadata from a jpeg or png file in exif format. I have therefore installed the "metadata-extractor" library on eclipse and copied the code below but it displays the error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class metadata.SampleUsage
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/drew/imaging/ImageProcessingException
```

Can you help me fix this?

```
package metadata;

import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentMetadataReader;
import com.drew.metadata.Directory;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.Tag;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifReader;
import com.drew.metadata.iptc.IptcReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Showcases the most popular ways of using the metadata-extractor library.
 * <p>
 * For more information, see the project wiki: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted
 *
 * @author Drew Noakes https://drewnoakes.com
 */
public class SampleUsage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("Tests/Data/withIptcExifGps.jpg");

        // There are multiple ways to get a Metadata object for a file

        //
        // SCENARIO 1: UNKNOWN FILE TYPE
        //
        // This is the most generic approach.  It will transparently determine the file type and invoke the appropriate
        // readers.  In most cases, this is the most appropriate usage.  This will handle JPEG, TIFF, GIF, BMP and RAW
        // (CRW/CR2/NEF/RW2/ORF) files and extract whatever metadata is available and understood.
        //
        try {
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);

            print(metadata, "Using ImageMetadataReader");
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            print(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            print(e);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Write all extracted values to stdout.
     */
    private static void print(Metadata metadata, String method)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.print(method);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        //
        // A Metadata object contains multiple Directory objects
        //
        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {

            //
            // Each Directory stores values in Tag objects
            //
            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
                System.out.println(tag);
            }

            //
            // Each Directory may also contain error messages
            //
            for (String error : directory.getErrors()) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + error);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(Exception exception)
    {
        System.err.println("EXCEPTION: " + exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you mean with "installed the library on eclipse"

Comment: Looks like you are missing a library. Make sure all libs are on the classpath.

Comment: I went to this link : https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.drewnoakes%20AND%20a:metadata-extractor , and I installed the .jar then on eclipse I went to the properties of my project then java build path then libraries and on modulepath I clicked on add external jar and I added the .jar that I downloaded before. After that I clicked on apply and close

Comment: But since I was able to import the elements of the library, it must have worked, right?

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem in the code itself

Comment: The only thing you know is that the library excpected a problem and tries to throw an Exception, that would contain the root cause.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer You will have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: @Giyu Find out in which ImageProcessingException are located. If you cant find it in your dependencies, it must be added somehow. After that - try again.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I have trouble finding it, I don't know where to start. I do not have a good grasp of the exceptions. Can you try the code I sent and see if it works on your end please

Comment: Where would someone be how to extract metadata in exif format from a png or jpeg file with this library or another?